# iOS in Settings app

Tags: ios, copy, settings

Good morning all, I was wondering if there is a way to capture a password while it is being typed in Settings . i.e. I am connecting to a Wifi hotspot and I need to save the typed password in NSUserDefaults. ?

Any thoughts ?
Much Thanks
JZ

Answer (score 1):

It would be pretty dangerous if you can read (whatever) system settings of iOs device - so in short - afaik it`s not possible. But you can make your own settings (which are shown in settings app) for your own app via [settings bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) - these settings you can use whatever you want.

Comment: Yes I had the same thought , that it would be dangerous. Maybe you have an idea for me. The way my app works is the user needs to access the Settings through this bit of code..                                                                              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
        });
After typing the password for wifi hotspot that same password needs to be accessed and sent over BLE Connection through a writeValue. Any thoughts on how to capture it?

Comment: I am not familiar with any way you can access this piece of information but you can do this in reverse order - maybe you can open your own prompt to enter password, you can store it and store it to clipboard, too. Then open the settings app - now user paste the same pass from clipboard and you are ready to go. - it`s not as good as you scenario, but the only known method (to me).

Comment: Yeah , I thought that as well, an extra step for the user but in the mean time. Thanks very much for your input. In the meantime I am reviewing the link you sent me. Thanks again Jz

Comment: Yeah, I have seen this approach in many apps which provides you something (typically wifi pass). The app stores it to clipboard and it`s up to user paste it to correct field.